# MoCA setup to increase WiFi range

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I'm trying to figure out how best to increase the coverage of the WiFi signal inside my apartment, and stumbled across setting up a MoCA network as a possible option, but all the examples I see seem to point to using it with a lot of wired devices, or having to connect another long ethernet cable between devices. I live in an apartment so I can't make destructive cable home mods. It's a long apartment, so the Wifi is fine in one area, but very bad in another.

My Wifi/Router combo is [this device](https://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/cable-modems-routers/C3000.aspx).

I only have devices connected via WiFI, save the modem/router combo I have. Here's my current setup:

```
|                       Back of apartment        |     Front of Apartment
|Bad Wifi                                        |               Good Wifi
|*coax outlet]----long coax cable----->----------|------->------|Modem/Router|
```

Proposed setup:

```
|                          Back of apartment        |   Front of Apartment       
|                                                   |
|*coax outlet]---[Coax splitter]---long coax cable--|--->----->-|Modem/Router|
|                       |                           | 
|                       |short coax cable           |
|                       v                           |
|             |Moca WiFI extender Device|           |
```

Questions:

1. Do I have the right idea for what can work? Or will I need another ethernet cable to connect the devices? If that's true, am I better off just buying a second wifi router?
2. Will I need to alter anything internally with the router to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea: using MoCA as an ethernet bridge between your router and your new access point. You might want to consider purchasing separate MoCA transceivers and a WiFi access point (I've found it's more cost-effective, easier to procure, and less painful to set up).

In the scenario you drew, make sure you install a MoCA POE (point of entry) filter onto the leg of the coax toward the cableco (where the coax enters your unit). If you don't use one, you might be sharing a network with your neighbours, and your cableco won't be very happy with the interference. They may have already installed one depending on your building's age and your services, but it shouldn't hurt to have two. (For example, some whole-home PVR systems use MoCA to play recordings on multiple receivers.)

You should also make sure that installing the splitter doesn't cause your cable modem's power levels or signal-to-noise ratios to exceed their acceptable levels. You can usually see this by browsing to your cable modem's statistics page. If this does happen, I'd suggest switching the position of the WiFi extender and modem, essentially using the line toward the front of the apartment as a standalone MoCA-only link (thus negating the need for a POE filter).